# Cannot upgrade to 17.04 from 16.04 on Kubuntu

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 17.04

I'm trying to upgrade to Zesty Zapus from Xenial with a Kubuntu client but neither Discover nor the recommended command line `kdesudo "do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE"` offers any upgrade possibility.

Comment: 16.04 is xenial, not 16.10 (yakkety) and that's the issue: 16.04 has LTS and, by default, the settings allow upgrade for a new LTS release only (that will be 18.04). You have to change that setting at Software Properties.

Comment: @MichaelBay Do we have verification of that?  (There's nothing here to support this)

Comment: @ThomasWard *"I'm trying to upgrade to Zesty Zapus from Xenial (...)"* I think is more plausible the name in text than the number in the title. Titles are, paradoxically, where we make more mistakes and proofread less. The answer (thank you comment) seems to confirm it was indeed xenial.

Comment: Yes, indeed it was my failure with the number - I was convinced to be on the latest version and after editing the title, queried  the current version and get the name from there. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

@MichaelBay - thank you for your advise, I changed this setting in the Update Manager / Advanced settings / Configure Software sources / Show new distribution releases to "Normal releases" and now it works.